# I need to add all database math into 1 answer PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, math, phpmyadmin

Pretty much I have about 1000 images stored in a folder, my php script shuffles all the images and displays 24 random ones each time the user refreshes the page.

In my database I have a table called 'images' with 3 columns, 'id, imagename and price'. Price is the value of each image ranging from something like 1-100 or so. In my database I currently only have 10 images with the destination to the original image and the price of that image.

Currently if one of those 10 images shows up on the screen it prints the price from the database next to the image. What I need help with is adding all of the prices together into 1 total sum.

CODE ---------

```
<?php

$username = "dbo556142743";
$password = "";
$hostname = "db556142743.db.1and1.com"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("db556142743",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");

?>

<?php

$picsdir = "images"; 

function getrandompic2($picsdir,$num_imgs) { 

   //chdir("."); 

    $clips = array(); 
    $dir = opendir($picsdir); 

   while ($f = readdir($dir)) { 
    $ext = substr($f,-4); 
   //      if($ext == ".JPG" || $ext == ".jpg") { 
    if($ext == ".jpg") { 
        $clips[] = $picsdir . "/" . $f;          
    } 
    $numfiles++; 
   } 
   closedir($dir); 

  //==$randpic = $clips[$p]; 
   $numbers = $clips; 
   $x = 0;  //counter for limit images 
   srand((float)microtime() * 1000000); 
   shuffle($numbers); 

    while (list(, $number) = each($numbers)) { 
       if ($x >= $num_imgs) return; 
    echo "<img src=" . "$number " . ">"; 

      $x++; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT imagename, price FROM images");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
//   echo "ImageName:".$row{'imagename'}."<br>Price:".$row{'price'}."<br>";

$price = $row['price'];

if ($row['imagename'] == $number){
    print $row['price']." ";
}
if ($row['imagename'] !== $number){
    print "ERROR!";
}

}

 } 

} 
  $num_imgs_to_show = 24; 

?>
<table width="40%">
    <th width="10%">
<?php       
  print getrandompic2($picsdir, $num_imgs_to_show) . "<br/ >"; 
?>
    </th>
</table>
```

Comment: We need the script.  Always post your code.

Comment: More specifically, always post the code *directly* relevant to your problem, not every bit of code you have on your hard drive.

Comment: Thanks @tadman, that is an important distinction!

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 0):

If by **"adding all of the prices together into 1 total sum"** you mean simple sum of prices of all images in your database, use SQL query `SELECT SUM(price) FROM images;`.